# GZipStream in HttpHandler: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, memorystream, ihttphandler, gzipstream

I'm writing a `HttpHandler`, which sends zipped file to the client on GET requests.

This code works well and sends unzipped data

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
  WriteMyDataToStream(mem);
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.csv");
  mem.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

but this code sends broken zip-files.

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
   var str = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress);
   WriteMyDataToStream(str);
   context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
   context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.zip");
   mem.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
   using(var str = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress))
   {
      WriteMyDataToStream(str);
      str.Flush();
      context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
      context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.zip");
      mem.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
   }
}
```

Now everything should be flushed to the `MemoryStream` and then forwarded to the `OutputStream` and then disposed.

*SIDE NOTE*:
`GZipStream` does NOT generate a `*.zip` file as you seem to expect it to. The correct extension would be `*.gz` (see Remarks [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)), but most decompression programms should be able to read it.

Comment: Good for pointing out the `*.gz` extension being the correct one. I think `DeflateStream` is the proper way to address `.zip` files.

Comment: According to MSDN `DeflateStream` uses the same algorithem as `GZipStream` and `ZipArchive` should be used für `*.zip`...

Comment: Useful information, I seem to have been mistaken. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to flush and explicitly close the compressing stream, like this:

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var str = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        WriteMyDataToStream(str);
        // force the compression stream buffer to be written to the mem stream
        str.Flush(); 

    }
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.zip");
    mem.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

The problem is that wrapper streams<sup>1</sup> may use internal buffering of the data (like the `GZipStream` does). This means the data passed to the buffering stream is written to its inner buffer, *but is not transferred to the main stream* yet. Calling `Flush()` would cause the stream to write all buffered data to the target stream and empty the buffer.

Note, that it is a good practice to dispose of your resources. By adding a `using` directive around the `str` variable, you will also dispose the compression stream, and its inner buffer.

---

<sup>1</sup> By *wrapper streams* I am referring to `Stream` implementations, which internally delegate to another `Stream` instance. It is possible, that the inner Stream is not immediately written to, when a corresponding Write method is called on the wrapper stream. Also, the inner stream could be a buffered stream itself (meaning the data is not actually written to the stream when a write method is called, but to a buffer). Therefore, flushing the wrapper stream prior closing it is needed to ensure the inner stream will have all the content written to it.